# Itunes app links are not working with WkWebview

Tags: ios, wkwebview, itms-90809

One of the webpage I load into Wkwebview has the following iTunes app link

```
 https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263?mt=8
```

when it's opened I'm getting the following alert

[image]

and here's the error that I've got.

```
{
    "[errorCode]" = 0;
    "[errorDescription]" = "Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)";
    "[errordetail]" = "Con:myappxxxx:myorder:webview:networkerror";
    "[localizedRecoverySuggestion]" = "";
    "[url]" = "itms-appss://apps.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263";
}
```

When the same iTunes link ( https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263?mt=8 )
 is opened in UIWebview , I saw that URL gets redirected to following URL and app opens in appstore

```
 itms-appss://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263?mt=8
```

Whereas in Wkwebview , the URL gets redirected to following URL

```
 itms-appss://apps.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263
```

Any help is appreciated

---

Update

I even tried Arbitrary uploads to true for transport security and the problem is still there.

> Error Domain= Code=0 "Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not
>   HTTP(S)"
>   UserInfo={_WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=itms-appss://apps.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=itms-appss://apps.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not
>   HTTP(S)}

Comment: check your `redirection to url with a scheme that is not https`

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more please ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could try to intercept the itunes link in wkwebview's delegate methods and open the URL using openURL

The below source code will open any itms-appss links in wkwebview. Don't forget to conform to ***WKNavigationDelegate***

```
   - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    if ([webURL.scheme isEqualToString:@"itms-appss"])
        {
                UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if ([app canOpenURL:webURL])
    {
        [self.webviewObj stopLoading];
        [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[webURL absoluteString]]];
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
     } else{
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
       }
        }
    else
       {
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
        }
     return;
    }
```

Comment: any ideas on which delegate I could try ... do I have to check for this particular URL " https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xx-yy-zz/id435919263?mt=8" and if found ... use the code snippet to open separately

Comment: You can look for the **scheme** and whether it's **itms-apps** then you can open the link using **openURL** or else you will have to put so many conditional checks for every itunes link that your webview's going to show and you may have to re-release the app everytime some new itunes links are added in the webpageto add a conditional check for that.

Comment: Please look into **WKNavigationDelegate** protocol methods , you will be able to find yourself.

Comment: I will look into that in the mean time , if you have any suggestion on which delegate method to look for , let me knwo

Comment: Try to intercept the URL here **- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler**

Comment: now the app opens successfully in appstore but my app crashes.i'm looking into that

Comment: @dineshR Make sure to call decisionHandler closure inside your delegate method implementation

Comment: Did not work with my http links to App Store (links were opened in the WKWebView and not redirected to the App Store app). So I use the same trick as described in this answer but checked if the URL contains the string "itunes.apple.com", and in this case I use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    i

Answer (score 4):

`WKWebView` seems **not to handle non-http(s) url schemas** by default.
So, you have to catch the request using `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)`, and check the url that can be loaded by `WKWebView`.
If the url is non-http(s) url, then you should open the url by `open(_:options:completionHandler:)`.

***Here the sample code.***

Assign the navigationDelegate for your `WKWebView`instance.

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Implement `WKNavigationDelegate` method.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    // if the url is not http(s) schema, then the UIApplication open the url
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
        !url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("http://"),
        !url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("https://"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {

        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        // cancel the request
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
        // allow the request
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your info.plist adding:

App transport Security settings
  -- Allow Arbitrary loads = yes

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit about what does this bit of code do and why is it necessary?

Comment: Apple implemented a "feature" to protect the user. you are not allowed to link to non https addresses, or it stops you with that error.  the plist entry overrides it.

I have a couple apps that use my own API, so i had to also over-ride it. You can over-ride it and it will still go through review.

Comment: that override allows all links. so even if your https redirects to a non secure site (http), it should let it go.. im using http, but it can be any non-secure protocol.

Comment: @Karl - Why is it not happening with UIWebview ?